# Jquery Pushdown/SlideDown conflict

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was following the fiddle I found here on stackoverflow

http://jsfiddle.net/abtPH/3/

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
});
```

And everything has worked as needed, however, when I click on multiple slide down they all must be closed in the order they were opened because they don't close once a new slide down has been clicked.

Is there a way to make each slide down close once a new slide down has been opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close the other `'.outer'` by targeting the clicked `'li'` siblings:

```
$('li').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
    //remove the active class, then move to its '.outer' child and slide it up
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').find('.outer').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark S is correct

still if you want to optimized code further you may write like this

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
  $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle().end().siblings().removeClass('active').find('.outer').slideUp();                  
  $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
});
```

Side Note:

In jsfiddele you have provided code div style="width: 156px; height: having inline styles declared. Its not good practice instead you can define class on div and declare respective styles in stylesheet